# How to create return to x?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, return

```
while True:
        print("Welcome to this BMI calculator")
        x = str(input("Are you using Pounds or Kg, if you are using Kg press K if you are using Pounds press P:"))
        if x in ['P', 'p']:
            h = float(input("Key in your weight:"))

        elif x in ['K', 'k']:
            h = float(input("Key in your weight:"))

        else:
            **return(x)**
            print(x)
```

> Bold indicates error
> and how to return if the user does not key in any of the characters (P/p/K/k)

Comment: As it sits, the problem is this is not a function.  You can't return from something that's not a function.  Did you intend for that to be a function?  Why would you want to return anyway?  And do you intend to do anything with the user's input?

Comment: And `input` always returns a string.  It's pointless to call `str()` there.

Comment: Yes I intend to do something with the user input. Yes I intend for it to be a function.

Comment: Once you make it a function, the `return` will work.

Comment: What do you want that `return` to do? Are you trying to make execution go back to the `x = ...` line?

Comment: Yes, if the user keys in the wrong thing it goes back to getting the user input

Comment: And how to use functions I'm pretty new to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to take user input and return the value - probably from a function? Then you should consider returning both `x` and `h` if you intend to use them further in your code.

```py
def input_weight():
    """Ask user for their weight and the metric system they want to use"""
    
    
    while True:
        x = input("Are you using Pounds or Kg, if you are using Kg press K if you are using Pounds press P:")
        
        if x in ['P', 'p', 'K', 'k']:
            break # user has provided correct metric
        else:
            print(x + " is not valid. try again")
            
    while True:
        try:
            h = float(input("Key in your weight:"))
        except ValueError:
            print("sorry this is not a valid weight. try again")
            continue
        else:
            break
            
    return h, x

print("Welcome to this BMI calculator")
h, x = input_weight()
print(h, x)
```

You may also want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response). There are several factors that has to be modified or changed in your code.

### Explanation

As you can see, there are two `while`-loop used in the function `input_weight()`.

1. the first loop will continue to ask user for metric system, and if a user inputs anything other than `['P', 'p', 'K', 'k']` then the loop will rerun prompting the user of wrong input.
2. similarly, the second loop asks user of weight. if the weight is anything but a number, then it will continue to ask user to provide proper input.